# How to upgrade table inside a trigger function in POSTGRESQL?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I would like to create a trigger function inside my database which checks, if the newly "inserted" value (`max_bid`) is at least +1 greater than the largest `max_bid` value currently in the table.
If this is the case, the `max_bid` value inside the table should be updated, although not with the newly "inserted" value, but instead it should be increased by 1.

For instance, if `max_bid` is 10 and the newly "inserted" `max_bid` is 20, the `max_bid` value inside the table should be increased by +1 (in this case 11).
I tried to do it with a trigger, but unfortunatelly it doesn't work. Please help me to solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE bidtable (
  mail_buyer VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  auction_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  max_bid INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (mail_buyer),
);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION max_bid()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $$
DECLARE
    current_maxbid INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(max_bid) INTO current_maxbid 
    FROM bidtable WHERE NEW.auction_id = OLD.auction_id;

    IF (NEW.max_bid < (current_maxbid + 1)) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'error';
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

    UPDATE bidtable SET max_bid = (current_maxbid + 1) 
    WHERE NEW.auction_id = OLD.auction_id
      AND NEW.mail_buyer = OLD.mail_buyer;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER max_bid_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON bidtable
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE max_bid();
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I understand that you want to increase by one max_bid when inserting a new row in table bidtable, dont' you ? Is so, I would suggest you to simply change the type of column max_bid from integer to serial. See the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)

Comment: @Edouard, that is not going to work for this case.  Pretty sure `max_bid` is a monetary value for an auction bid.

Comment: 1) `RAISE EXCEPTION 'error';` is going to stop the function from doing any further processing. Even if you change that to `RAISE NOTICE 'error';` then the `RETURN NULL;` is going to do the same thing, return from function with no further processing. 2) This `UPDATE bidtable SET max_bid = (current_maxbid + 1)...` can be simplified to `NEW max_bid = current_maxbid + 1`. 3) Spend some time reading this [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html). 4) Why do want to constrain the bid like this?

Comment: You should **not** issue an DML statement within a trigger against the table that fired the trigger. Here just use simple assignment: `new.max_bid = current_maxbid + 1;` However, even this is poor practice. You face the MAX+1 issue which in a multi-user environment is a virtual guarantee you will get a duplicate. I echo @Edouard use serial or better an [identity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) column. Note: you will get gaps, but you will not get duplicates.

Comment: @Belayer, I think you are missing the point. That is to constrain any new bids to one over the current max bid. `serial/identity` is not going to work for this.

Answer (score 0):

In a trigger function that is called for an `INSERT` operation the `OLD` implicit record variable is null, which is probably the cause of "unfortunately it doesn't work".

### Trigger function

In a case like this there is a much easier solution. First of all, disregard the value for `max_bid` upon input because you require a specific value in all cases. Instead, you are going to set it to that specific value in the function. The trigger function can then be simplified to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_max_bid()  -- Function name different from column name
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $$
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(max_bid) + 1 INTO NEW.max_bid 
    FROM bidtable
    WHERE auction_id = NEW.auction_id;
    RETURN NEW;
END; $$;
```

That's all there is to it for the trigger function. Update the trigger to the new function name and it should work.

### Concurrency

As several comments to your question pointed out, you run the risk of getting duplicates. This will currently not generate an error because you do not have an appropriate constraint on your table. Avoiding duplicates requires a table constraint like:

```
UNIQUE (auction_id, max_bid)
```

You cannot deal with any concurrency issue in the trigger function because the `INSERT` operation will take place **after** the trigger function completes with a `RETURN NEW` statement. What would be the most appropriate way to deal with this depends on your application. Your options are [table locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/explicit-locking.html) to block any concurrent inserts, or [looping in a function until the insert succeeds](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING).

### Avoid the concurrency issue altogether

If you can change the structure of the `bidtable` table, you can get rid of the whole concurrency issue by changing your business logic to not require the `max_bid` column. The `max_bid` column appears to indicate the order in which bids were placed for each `auction_id`. If that is the case then you could add a `serial` column to your table and use that to indicate order of bids being placed (for all auctions). That serial column could then also be the `PRIMARY KEY` to make your table more agile (no indexing on a large `text` column). The table would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE bidtable (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  mail_buyer VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  auction_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

You can drop your trigger and trigger function and just depend on the proper `id` value being supplied by the system.

The bids for a specific action can then be extracted using a straightforward `SELECT`:

```
SELECT id, mail_buyer
FROM bidtable
WHERE auction_id = xxx
ORDER BY id;
```

If you require a `max_bid`-like value (the `id` values increment over the full set of auctions), you can use a simple window function:

```
SELECT mail_buyer, row_number() AS max_bid OVER (PARTITION BY auction_id ORDER BY id)
FROM bidtable
WHERE auction_id = xxx;
```